# Как подключить PyGame в PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pygame

Как подключить библиотеку PyGame в PyCharm?
Команда `pip install pygame` не работает. Добавление различных букв (w, u и др.) также не помогает.

Попытки подключения библиотеки через Python также не дают результата. На официальном сайте PyGame полезной информации нет. Только `pip install pygame` для подключения.

Comment: 1) Ставите pygame в интерпретатор питона 2) В PyCharm у текущего проекта в настройках проекта указываете тот интерпретатор, в который ставили 3) Профит

Comment: Возможно, у вас в проекте в PyCharm есть питон в виртуальном окружении. В той же настройке проекта можно установить библиотеки через `+`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но я ничего не понимаю. Что за виртуальное окружение? Подозреваю, что у меня нет этого виртуального окружения. Я пытался запустить через IDLE, Консоль Python и в самом Python. Не знаю есть ли среди перечисленного интерпретатор. Также PyCharm на английском, а я английский не знаю, поэтому не знаю куда нажимать в настройках

Comment: Добавил описание в качестве ответа - комментарии для такого плохо предназначены :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В PyCharm:

- Открываете меню File/Settings...
- Переходите в Project/Python Interpreter

Там можно выбрать (1) или создать (2) интерпретатор питона, а так же устанавливать (3) в них библиотеки.

Выбранный там интерпретатор будет использоваться при запуске скриптов в проекте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз. Сейчас более понятно. Зашёл куда было сказано и нажал там +, в новом окне ввёл 'pygame' и нажал install. Потом высветилось "Package 'pygame' installed successfully". И я закрыл то окно, но в изначальном окне было "Error occurred when installing package 'pygame'". Я посмотрел подробнее и там было "Troubleshooting steps: 1. Try reading PyCharm guide on troubleshooting package installation. 2. Try installing this package by running the following comands is the terminal. If the command crashes in the terminal, the problem is out of IDE control." Но по итогу всё работает, проверял.

Comment: Добавлю ещё, что в окне деталей о ошибке при установке было внутреннее окно с текстом. Я его через переводчик перевёл и там сказано, что отсутствует файл setup, поэтому будет через windows что-то делаться (я не помню точно). Надеюсь, что это не что-то важное.